# Wordpress - ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on long content

Tags: wordpress

I am completely stumped here. I have a site where when I update some of the pages, Wordpress gives me ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE page, and only updates part of the page. I can see that a revision is made but it only shows part of the page that I have tried to update.

I have done several tests:

1. Using another device - this works for a while but after sometime time of updating the pages it starts to return the same error.
2. Adding test pages with short content. This works on any device. I am able to add a page with a small amount of content on.
3. I thought it may be a hack so wiped the server and added a new totally stripped back wordpress install with a new database. Most basic install. I was able to add short content but anything long it came back with the same error. I was also unable to upload plugins as it would timeout.
4. If I am in blocks editor, it comes back with a slightly different error that says something like "Can't be updated. You may be offline" (but I think essentially the same as ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in classic editor).
5. I logged into another of my sites on a different server and managed to add long content (in fact exact same content that I tried to add on the broken site as my test), I managed to add this without any issue.

I have the same problem in both Chrome and Safari (albeit safari gives a different page error in classic editor which I can't remember now, but essentially the same and the page can't be updated properly.

I think this is a server issue but I have no idea why?

The thing that puzzles me the most is why would I be able to edit the site on a new device that I haven't used to edit the site before with out issue for a time, and then after an undetermined amount of time, it stops working and encounters the same problems as described above. I have experienced this on three different laptops now.

I have cleared caches repeatedly in browsers and in wordpress. I have also reinstalled my chrome browser.

I have trawled the internet to find a similar error and carried out any fixes that are suggested but as yet nothing has worked.

It is totally random. Has anyone else experienced this or has any clue why this would be happening?

Many thanks

Clojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed!

After troubleshooting for 3 days the hosting company agreed to switch the site to a new server. As soon as they did the site start working and I could upload stuff.

They have no idea why there was a problem with the old server as they said that they try and keep the configs the same. They checked the php.ini and the user.ini and apparently everything as it should be. There was not Max data being sent, or at least there was but loads and loads. More than you would ever require. Time outs were set for 30 mins. (Sorry I don’t know the tech terms but all the stuff in the php file that set the times and amount of data and stuff.)

If anyone ever finds out what the reason is it would be great for other people that are experiencing the same issue. I have searched high and low and there are quite a few that have experienced this exact problem but no real solutions are out there apart from the switching of servers. If we knew the reason on server front, the host company would be able to fix. Maybe wordpress will know?

Anyway, for now it is fixed here and I’m so happy!

Clojo